# Download SOS.dll by version number

Tags: download, windbg, sos

I got a mini dump that requires SOS.dll 4.0.30319.1008, however the winDBG failed to download the correct dll.  The symbol path has already been set to `SRV*C:\symcache*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols`

Does anyone know where to download the SOS.dll by providing the version number?
I decided to download the dll manually and replace it to the Microsoft.net fold under windows.

Comment: You can get the appropriate version of SOS.dll on the same machine that the dump was created on. You should not replace the version on your machine. Just use .load <path> to load it. If you debug dumps frequently, I recommend keeping a repository of all unique versions of SOS that you come across.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Update**: [I published a blog post on how to open snapshots collected on other machines](https://github.com/mitikov/KeepSitecoreSimple/wiki/Opening-Memory-Snapshots-generated-on-other-machines-locally)

---

Please try to do following steps if you do not have needed SOS & CLR assemblies from target machine:

- **.sympath c:\symbols**  //[setSymPath]
- **.symfix+** //[perform a try to download needed assemblies. Would take ages for the first time
- **.cordll -ve -u -l** // try to load needed assemblies automatically
- **.reload** // just-in-case

If it does not work [rare case], a set of steps to be performed:

1. **SOS** an **CLR** assemblies are included into Microsoft updates, so ***you need to pull the same update that is installed on the target machine*** ( where memery dump was captured ). Here is a link to repo :  http://www.mskbfiles.com/sos.dll.php
2. Download needed update and unzip it a couple of times [ f.e. you will get 'GDRGDR.cab' and 'QFEGDR.cab' files -> unzip them too ]
3. The resulting folders would have needed assemblies named like: 'clr_dll_amd64' -> should rename to clr.dll
4. You will need to find needed ones ( CPU architecture, bitness matters )
5. You may load it into the Windbg using **.load c:\mytempfolder\NDP40-KB2835393-x64\QFEGDR\sos** **[Only exact assembly match would work]**
6. Upon files are loaded, use **.reload** command just-in-case

Hope this helps =)

Answer (score 4):

I have not investigated in full detail, but it seems that WinDbg downloads SOS.dll for a .NET dump if you type `!analyze -v`. Also, [DebugDiag](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40336)  seems to load SOS.dll when you do a dump analysis.

If none of the options works, run [Mscordacwkscollector](http://debugging.wellisolutions.de/download-mscordacwks-collector/) on the machine where the dump was created.

I also maintain an [archive of debugging DLLs](http://www.sos.debugging.wellisolutions.de/).

Comment: Thomas, looks like the archive is down. Was it relocated? I had found it helpful

Comment: @JeffreyLeCours: oh, I seem to accidentally have deleted it along with my business. I'll look into this. I've not maintained it for a long time, but sure, it may still be useful, even to me :-)